# Rails link_to functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I know there is the link_to function in ruby on rails, and it works well for standard paths when you want to link to a controller action.  Just wondering, is there any way of listing the functions which can be used - using activeadmin and trying to put a link on the dashboard to create a new object, but can't find the right function.

Thoughts or suggestions would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line at the root of your rails app type `rake routes`. This will show you paths all the standard routes in your app. I haven't used activeadmin but it may show routes for that as well.

Comment: Awesome! I was gonna mention rake routes and see if there were any equivalent for functions but it turns out it does both!

Comment: Also: should these functions always be in scope?